# Error: Unable to access jarfile start.jar - System cannot find the path specified (when loading GeoServer)

Tags: java, jar, geoserver

I am trying to install Geoserver in Windows 10 following the instructions of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r97I2jiajiw&ab_channel=krishnalodha.
I installed Geoserver and Java. I defined the Environment variables as shown in the video. I ran the startup.bat file as an administrator and i get the following error:
[image]

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile start.jar

System cannot find the path specified
```

The start.jar file is in the GEOSERVER folder.

I have tried to define the path seperators from the Environment Variables window as '\','\\' and '/' but Geoserver doesn't load in any case.
I have installed the latest version of Java in my system.
I set start.jar file to open with javaw.exe file.
It keeps giving me the same error.

What can i do to fix this error?

Has anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "Platform Independent Binary" version of GeoServer then you should not need to set any environment variables. Just double click on the `start.bat` and it will start with no issues (providing that it can find Java on your path, otherwise setting `JAVA_HOME` will help).

In general, you shouldn't use that install for anything important as it is not designed for security or performance.

Answer (score 0):

I found what caused the error. I had saved the folders *Java* and *GEOSERVER* in my HDD (D:). I removed the folders *Java* and *GEOSERVER* in the Program Files folder of my SSD (C:\Program Files) and the GeoServer loads correctly.

Answer (score 0):

please go to the install directory where start.jar is, for example, D:\Program Files\GeoServer,  then open the cmd in the dir, input the code: java -jar start.jar